# accessing soket.io server from a remote hosted page - require undifined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to access a socket.io server hosted on heroku from a remote client. I am using the client hosted site on xampp running on my pc.

There is an issue with the client side JavaScript `const io = require("socket.io-client");`

This throws a console error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at (index):28`

Most searches of this error return an issue around referencing the socket.io.js file. I have used several methods to reference the script and I believed they all worked throwing the same error. I know they worked because if I view the source, click the script it loads up.

The app is just the basic chat get started example on the socket.io website with a few minor changes.

Client side code is below:

```
`
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
      </head>
      <body>
        <ul id="messages"></ul>
        <form id="form" action="">
            <div>
                <span id="user-typing"></span>
            </div>
          <input id="input" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
        </form>
    
        <div id="name-container">
            <span>Username: </span>
            <input type="text" id="username">
    
        </div>
        <!-- <script src="https://app-chat.herokuapp.com/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> -->
        <script src="socket.js"></script>
     
        <script>
    
    
    
              const io = require("socket.io-client");
              const socket = io("https://app-chat.herokuapp.com/", {
                withCredentials: true,
                extraHeaders: {
                  "my-custom-header": "abcd"
                }
      });
            
            var username = "user" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000) + 1);
    
            var messages = document.getElementById('messages');
            var notice = document.getElementById('user-typing');
            var form = document.getElementById('form');
            var input = document.getElementById('input');
          
            form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              if (input.value) {
                socket.emit('chat message', input.value);
                input.value = '';
              }
            });
    
            input.addEventListener('input', function (evt) {
                socket.emit('user typing', username);
            });
          
            socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
              var item = document.createElement('li');
              username = document.getElementById("username").value;
              item.innerHTML = "<b>" + username + "</b>" + ": " + msg;
              messages.appendChild(item);
              window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
            });
    
            socket.on('user typing', function(msg) {
              notice.innerHTML = msg + " is typing a message";
            });
          </script>
    
      </body>
    </html>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Require doesn't exist in browsers.

To import modules you have to use sth like [browserify](https://github.com/browserify/browserify)

Or use `<script src='pathToFileOrCdn></script>`
Anywhere before using socket.io

Comment: What I have added is exactly like the socket.io docs have. I have imported the socket.io.js script, that's what I assumed would allow the require function to work.

Comment: No, because `require() ` doesn't exist in the browser. You have to reference the socket js file through the `script` tag.